# Convert Date (dd/mm/YYY) to from factor to numeric

Tags: r, class

I am trying to convert the variable below from a factor with 542 levels to a Date which is recognised by R as numeric. I am very new to R and was unable to follow the explanations in other threads.

Thanks a lot!
Sara

[screen shot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCQXs.png)

Comment: share data please instead of sharing the screenshot

Comment: This maybe helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160732/factor-as-date-to-numeric

Comment: Furthermore: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I shall take that on board in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're after ISO8601 YYYYMMDD formated numbers, how about this?

```
dates <- c("18/08/2015","19/08/2015")
dateNumbers <- as.numeric(as.character(as.Date(dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), format="%Y%m%d"))
dateNumbers
[1] 20150818 20150819
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I think it might! I have a further issue which is that for some reason my dates are in two different formats as follows: > data1 <- c("21/01/2015","22-01-2015")
> dateNumbers <- as.numeric(as.character(as.Date(data1, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), format="%Y%m%d"))
> dateNumbers
[1] 20150121       NA

Comment: It appears it is not possible to do paragraphs in the comments boxes, sorry!

Comment: I have finally managed to tidy my data, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Your screenshot looks like a vector. So try this:

```
lapply(some_vec, function(date) gsub('-', '', date) )
```

EDIT: 
May be you need to reformat the date with:

```
some_vec <- as.Date(some_vec, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

before.

EDIT2:

First the code:

```
some_vec <- rep(factor(as.Date('18/08/2015', format = '%d/%m/%Y')), 30)
some_vec <- as.Date(some_vec, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
res <- unlist(lapply(some_vec, function(date) { 
   gsub('-', '', date)
}))
res
[1] "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818"
[15] "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818" "20150818"
[29] "20150818" "20150818"
```

I tried to help blindfolded here. So, please don't be harsh. What I tried is to reformat the date (if even necessary). On my System R shows the date already in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format (before the reformating).

```
some_vec
[1] 2015-08-18 2015-08-18 2015-08-18 2015-08-18 2015-08-18 2015-08-18 ...
[29] 2015-08-18 2015-08-18
Levels: 2015-08-18
```

Once the data has this format you can lapply over the list and kill the '-' signs.

Comment: What is the first comamnd supposed to achieve? Your format string doesn't correspond to the date format in the data.

Comment: Start with `some_vec <- rep(factor('18/08/2015'), 30)` to reproduce OP's problem. `gsub` is not needed here. They probably want to have `Date`s. If they really want `numeric`s, they probably simply need to use `as.numeric` on the `Date`s. You shouldn't answer such unclear questions.

Comment: I won't in future! `as.numeric` wouldn't work here! Not for the factors nor the dates.

Comment: `as.numeric` can of course turn `Date`s into `numeric`s: `as.numeric(as.Date("2016-01-15"))`

Comment: I know it can! I meant the reasonability to do so in this particular case.